# php image resize function outputs the replacement character (lots of times)

Tags: php, image, resize-image

I have stitched together various pieces from tutorials to use php to resize an image. Here is my image resize function (note:the relative path to the image is definitely correct).

```
function resizeImg() {
  $source_image = imagecreatefrompng('images/myImage.png');
  $source_imagex = imagesx($source_image);
  $source_imagey = imagesy($source_image);

  $dest_imagex = 16;
  $dest_imagey = 22;
  $dest_image = imagecreatetruecolor($dest_imagex, $dest_imagey);
  imagecopyresampled($dest_image, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $dest_imagex, $dest_imagey, $source_imagex, $source_imagey);
  header("Content-Type: image/png");
  imagepng($dest_image,NULL,9);
}
```

The function is called as follows:

```
<img src="<?php resizeImg(); ?>" alt=img">
```

However, not only does the image output as the default broken img icon, but it is surrounded by dozens of the replacement character �.

I thought perhaps the function was not returning anything, so I inserted at the end of the function:

```
return $dest_image;
```

with no effect.

Can anybody please tell me why my function doesn't perform as anticipated?

Comment: Your function emits raw image data but the `src` attribute of the `<img>` tag expects a URL.

Comment: I tried using base64_decode() on the raw data, followed by returning the result of imagecreatefromstring($img) but still the same...any pointers?

Comment: Did you add a data:image in your src tag? Like <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO 9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when you use imagepng and headers, this only works in a separate script, like:

```
<img src="theResizeScript.php">
```

And this only works if is not present other output for the script.

Any way, you can use ob_start and ob_end to capture the output like this:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,<?php echo resizeImg(); ?>" alt="img"/>

<?php
function resizeImg() {

    $source_image = imagecreatefrompng('images/image.png');
    $source_imagex = imagesx($source_image);
    $source_imagey = imagesy($source_image);

    $dest_imagex = 16;
    $dest_imagey = 22;
    $dest_image = imagecreatetruecolor($dest_imagex, $dest_imagey);
    imagecopyresampled($dest_image, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $dest_imagex, $dest_imagey, $source_imagex, $source_imagey);

    ob_start();
    imagepng($dest_image,NULL,9);
    $image_data = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    return base64_encode($image_data);
}
```

Of course remember to use the "data:image/png;base64" in your image source tag.